# Is a query inside mysql IF clause allowed?

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertUser`(IN passwd VARCHAR(100), IN userType VARCHAR(20), IN mobileNo VARCHAR(20), IN refId BIGINT(20), IN companyName VARCHAR(100), IN companyMail VARCHAR(200), IN status CHAR(1)  )
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
DECLARE c VARCHAR(20);
Select COUNT(*) from `user` into c where `mobile_no` = mobileNo;

IF c > 0 
THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Mobile Number Exists';
ELSE



    INSERT INTO `user`
        (   
        `password` , 
    `user_type` ,
        `mobile_no` ,
        `reference_id` ,
        `company_name` ,
        `company_mail_id` ,
        `status`
        )
  
    VALUES 
        (
        pass , 
        usertype ,
        mobileno ,
        refid ,
        companyName ,
        companyMail ,
        status
        );
END;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone point out the error? It might be something very small, but I've tried a lot, and I'm just not able to make this run.

Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `mobile_no` = mobileNo;

```
IF c > 0
THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '' at line 7
```

Comment: What error message is returned?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
DECLARE c VARCHAR(20);
Select COUNT(*) from user into c where mobile_no = mo' at line 4

Comment: I've tried writing this in various ways! First I was directly comparing the result of count inside if, that did not work, so I wrote it as a separate query

Comment: Im sorry Matt, I somehow forgot to write that here.. the whole code is inside the handler.. error remains the same.. its near c >0 , is such a comparison allowed?

Comment: This is the actual code, copy/pasted this time - http://www.shrib.com/sqlproblem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you're getting from that exact version of the procedure.

Comment: Just did that Mat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error

This is not the right SQL for getting the count

```
Select COUNT(*) from `user` into c where `mobile_no` = mobileNo;
```

You do not put `into c` after the from clause. It goes before it.

Therefore, this is correct SQL syntax

```
Select COUNT(*) into c from `user` where `mobile_no` = mobileNo;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you! never thought it would be so minute. A voteup requires reputation and I'm new here, but definitely a voteup from my side.